# Maximum distance between two unit norm vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I have 2 random vectors. I want to limit the euclidean distance between those two vectors to a certain  number (say 2) by normalizing them. I think that if I normalize them such that they have a unit (L2) norm then any two vectors arbitrarily selected of any dimensionality will have the distance between them at most equal to 2.  Is this correct? If not, is there any way to achieve this. Remember, vectors can take any real values and can have any number of dimensions.

Also, how would I do it if I want to limit the cosine distance of any two vectors to a certain value?

Comment: What do you mean by the 'cosine distance'?

Comment: I mean the cosine similarity between two vectors. But I realized that for any two vectors cosine similarity would take value between 0 and 1.

Comment: Do you mean the $\cos$ of the angle between the two vectors?

Comment: I added a comment to the answer below; does that answer your second question?

Comment: Yes, cosine of the angle between two vectors.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If $\|x\|=\|y\| = 1$, the triangle inequality gives $\|x-y\| \le \|x\| + \|y\| = 2$. This is true for **any** norm.

Since the two vectors are have unit norm, we can define the angle between them with $\cos \theta = \langle x, y \rangle$. If you have some constraint on $\theta$, you can translate that into a check on $\langle x, y \rangle$.

Then keep generating random vectors until they satisfy the criterion. The criterion needs to have a positive probability of being true.